# MMDDYYYY date format comparsion in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I Just started to use `Awk`. Here I include my `awk` code which is used for retrieve the names of person who are all born on or before **05171997**

```
awk -F "\t" '(substr($2,5,4)<1997||(substr($2,5,4)==1997 && substr($2,1,2)<=05 && substr($2,3,2)<=17)) {print $1}' <input.txt
```

Data at the input.txt

```
Bharath 01061992
Ragul   10302002
Bala    01171993
Arjun   05142003
Vimal   06301997
Ramesh  05171997
Kamal   05151997
Vinoth  05201997
```

It just fine for Now. I want to know Is there any other best way to compare two dates than my method of comparison?

Comment: Can you share some sample lines from your input file? What is `$2` ?

Comment: Concatenate the substrings together into YYYYMMDD order and then you can just use a single comparison.

Comment: I had to do `int(substr($2,5,4))` to make the above work. Also used `<=1997` in the date comparison (if you use both `&&` and `||` you might need parenthesis to indicate priority). Finally, if you are dealing with dates a lot, consider using [epoch timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Answer (score 2):

You can rearrange them into the ISO date format, which can easily be used for arithmetic comparisons.

Assuming you have GNU awk(for gensub).

```
awk -F'\t' -vdate="19970517" 'date>=gensub(/(....)(....)/,"\\2\\1",1,$2){print $1}' f
```

produces

```
Bharath 
Bala    
Ramesh  
Kamal
```